# Adding Google Map API Key to Distance Calc Function

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code and have signed up and received an API key from google but do not know where to place the key. Can anyone help me on where the key should go?

```
Distance_Calc
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
    firstVal = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
    secondVal = "&destinations="
    lastVal = "&mode=car&language=pl&sensor=false"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """distance"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
    GetDistance = CDbl(tmpVal)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    GetDistance = -1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [Directions Matrix web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/) from java.  If that is on the client, it is not recommended (and makes it hard to secure your key as the [web service requires a "server key"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key#types-of-api-keys)). If it is on the server, use a server key (and protect it), [specifying it in the request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key#specify-a-key-in-your-request).

example ([from the documentation](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&key=YOUR_API_KEY)):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

In your case, you can add it to the `lastVal` you append to the request (and remove the no longer required `sensor` parameter):

```
lastVal = "&mode=car&language=pl&key=YOUR_API_KEY"
```

To use the directions matrix from javascript on the client, use the [Google Maps Javascript API Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix), and use a [browser key when you include the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#get-an-api-key)

Comment: I am not using on a server...just my own PC. Are you suggesting to put the lastVal = "&mode=car&language=pl&key=YOUR_API_KEY" before the Exit Function line above

Comment: Replace the existing definition.  Get a server key for your PC's ip address/hostname (as seen in the request to Google's servers).